# Resizing div according to the textarea

Tags: html, css

I created a div to create this input area, however, it's evident that this div will run across the whole page. Whenever I try to style, say add a border under the legend, the border runs across the full page. What I want is to restrict the width of the div to the textarea box, so that even the border runs across only from the start of the textarea to the end of the textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `block` element will grow to occupy the available inner width of it's parent. To have it shrink down to the size of it's largest child, use `display: inline-block` instead.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_area">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input Text</legend>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! However, surprisingly now I am not able to center this div of mine. margin: 0 auto; does not do anything, and when I do text-align: center; it just centers the "Input Text"

Comment: @TheBolt use `text-align: center` on the parent of `#input_area`

Answer (score 1):

you can put a wrapper around it assuming you wanted it on its own line:

```
<div>
  <div id="input_area">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Input Text</legend>
      <textarea rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then with your css change your input area to an inline block.

```
#input_area {display: inline-block;}
```